# Loop through multiple array in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 2 arrays here one contains the servername and other contains the IP.

I need to loop through them and create a key value pair like below for each server

```
server1:ip1
server2:ip2
```

I have written below code, but the problem is if i debug the code using F11, it is working fine, but i don't it gives some error which is different every time.

so feeling like it is not that reliable piece to continue.

```
    $NewDNSEntryName = $DNSEntryName.Split(",")
    $DNSIPs = $DNSIP.Split(",")


if($DNSEntryName -match "," -or $DNSIP -match ",")
    {   

   0..($NewDNSEntryName.Count - 1) | ForEach-Object {

   $fullName=""
   $fullName += @("$($NewDNSEntryName[$_]):$($DNSIPs[$_])")
```

This is the line where i am facing trouble

```
0..($NewDNSEntryName.Count - 1) | ForEach-Object
```

Please let me know why this code is behaving like this else any alternate idea is appreciated

Comment: Can you update your question with some specific issues/errors you are getting?

Comment: Does each list align exactly? If so, you can use a standard `for` loop and access the same index among each list. So `$NewDNSEntryName[0]` and `$DNSIPs[0]` would correspond.

Comment: There is no error. what it does it directly comes out of the loop without executing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each item in each list corresponds with each other exactly, you can use a `for` loop and loop through the array indexes.

```
$NewDNSEntryName = $DNSEntryName.Split(",")
$DNSIPs = $DNSIP.Split(",")

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $DNSIPs.count; $i++) {
    "{0}:{1}" -f $NewDNSEntryName[$i],$DNSIPs[$i]
}
```

For the code above to work, `$DNSEntryName` and `$DNSIP` must be single strings with commas between names and IPs. If `$DNSEntryName` and `$DNSIP` are already lists or arrays, something else will need to be done.

In your attempt, technically, your logic should work given everything written above is true. However, `$fullName` is emptied at every single iteration, which may produce undesirable results.

Comment: Thanks @AdminOfThings